# Using gradle 2.4 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'd like to use the latest version of Gradle in Android Studio. How do I check which version is used, and how do I upgrade to the latest one (if it is supported)? I would like to upgrade because I read that the latest version of Gradle improves build times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check current Gradle version in Project Structure (File -> Project Structure...).
[image: How to check Gradle version in Android Studio]

You can change default Gradle by using local distribution. However, I am not sure if Android Studio can support Gradle 2.4. Maybe you can have a try. Or you can change gradle-wrapper.properties directly.
[image: How to change default Gradle]

Comment: I missed that setting in the project structure dialog. It is enough to change that value to 2.4 to use the new version of gradle, bringing down build times sensibly. It does really feels snappier (and the project I am working on compiles fine, so I don't think there is any compatibility problem. At least I hope so).