# Reduce Gradle sync time in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using a mac with 16gb memory, ssd hdd and still Gradle sync takes 15mins+ every time I build, clean or open the project, are there any Android Studio optimisations possible to reduce this time.

-----update----

All of these helped to some extent

1. replace all compile 'com.package.:+' with appropriate versions, check maven repos for the latest build, better practise to develop on a version than dynamic updates, it may introduce bugs or issues.
2. close project and restart mac/windows.
3. Update Android studio if there is one
4. updating gradle version
5. turn on gradle daemon, parallel daemons and increase heap size in gradle.properties

> org.gradle.daemon=true
>
> org.gradle.parallel=true
>
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
>       -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError .   //increase Xmx and  -XX:MaxPermSize accordingly

6. Reorder your repositories and put google's repos first. Bintray, jcenter, maven repos may have missing or corrupt google play/ google services dependencies resulting in fetch delays

example:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()         //1st priority in search
    repo2()
    repo3()
    repo4()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()        //least priority, when not found in all above repos
}
```

Comment: same issue here, any luck finding a fix?

Comment: All of these helped to some extent

1)replace all compile 'com.package.:+' with appropriate versions, check maven repos for the latest build, better practise to develop on a version than dynamic updates, it may introduce bugs or issues.
2)close project and restart mac/windows.
3)Update Android studio if there is one
4)changing gradel version to 2.4 didn't help me but you can try that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably using a `+` symbol on the libraries you added to your project (and have a very slow internet connection). For example: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'`

This will make on every sync() gradle will check online if there's a new version. If you change to specific version number, for example: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'`

Then gradle will use the cached version that already been downloaded to your development machine.

Comment: Still build times range up to an insane15-17 mins, does the @arr portion also needs to be removed ?

Comment: I agree it's insane. I work on a quite big project and first sync is just a minute or so. What flower green commented is also very valid. There's been lots of efforts from the gradle n Google teams to speed it up on latest versions, manner sure to grab the very latest.

Comment: I'm here in 2018 and syncing gradle for an NDK project still takes ages. What I dont understand, how can checking for an updated version take such a time? It's only a few bytes to check the current\newest version

Answer (score 1):

I would try to change the gradle version of your project to 2.4. If I recall correctly, studio uses 2.2 by default. I tried and I got slightly better build times on a small project. Maybe you can get better improvements.

Here you can find how: [Using gradle 2.4 in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684967/using-gradle-2-4-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to

> File->Settings->Gradle

and tick the Offine work check box

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the answer! You wouldn't be able to update any dependencies from the web