# Error creating new project or opening existing projectafter Android Studio 2.3 updates

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, project, new-project

I updated my Android studio to new version 2.3 and when trying to create new project or reopen existing project and following error blocks my way. Please help me.

**Find error screen below**

[image]

[image]

Thank You

Comment: I hope you find your answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829072/reduce-gradle-sync-time-in-android-studio

Comment: @Rachit Thanks for your answer but I am looking for Android Studio 2.3 (Release Date 2nd March 2017) Updates related issues not about gradle.

Comment: People don't understand the question seems to rate -1......... Please comment on it don't ****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now I uninstall Android Studio 2.3 and switch back to older version 2.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to solve:

1. Update all pending updates
2. clear the cache
3. restart android studio