Gradle Compilation Issue with Kotlin Project: Memory Management and Generics
I'm encountering a serious issue with compiling my Kotlin project using Gradle. The problem occurs specifically during the compileKotlin task and seems to be related to memory management.
Configuration:
I have the following on my gradle.properties file:
# Increase heap size and metaspace size
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails
kotlin.daemon.jvmargs=-Xmx16g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails

# Enable build cache
org.gradle.caching=true

# Enable parallel build
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enable incremental build
org.gradle.incremental=true

Issue Description:
The compilation time fluctuates dramatically. With small code changes, the compilation process can take several minutes to hours and sometimes never completes. The build seems to hang indefinitely.
I suspect that extensive use of generics might be impacting the compiler's performance, but I'm not sure if this is the root cause.
Example Debug Output:
2024-07-30T22:52:20.628-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-30T22:52:25.397-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.DefaultMemoryManager] 1707250073 physical memory requested, 832716800 free
2024-07-30T22:52:25.397-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonExpiration] Will attempt to release 1628 of memory
2024-07-30T22:52:25.397-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.DefaultMemoryManager] 1707250073 physical memory requested, 0 released, 832716800 free
2024-07-30T22:52:30.396-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.DefaultMemoryManager] 1707250073 physical memory requested, 827449344 free
2024-07-30T22:52:30.396-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonExpiration] Will attempt to release 1628 of memory
2024-07-30T22:52:30.396-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.DefaultMemoryManager] 1707250073 physical memory requested, 0 released, 827449344 free
...

Questions:

Could the extensive use of generics in my code be causing these performance issues?
Are there specific configurations or best practices for managing memory in Kotlin/Gradle builds to improve performance?
How can I diagnose and resolve this problem effectively?

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:

I have already tried increasing JVM memory settings.
Gradle build cache and parallel builds are enabled.
I'm using the latest stable version of Gradle (8.9) and Kotlin 1.9.21.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Have you specified both kotlin.daemon.jvmargs and org.gradle.jvmargs ?

@RoarS. Yes, and I get the same result. I edited the question with that details, thanks!

Without knowing your build environment; could you try to reduce org.gradle.jvmargs to 1g and leave kotlin.daemon.jvmargs as is?

@RoarS. I tried that and the issue persists

Posting on YouTrack would probably be better to get the attention of the Kotlin developers. (They'll likely want a reproducible example of the problem.)

Have you added org.gradle.daemon=true? , check this link for more -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829072/reduce-gradle-sync-time-in-android-studio?rq=2
